# How to increase timeout for NGINX for windows?

Tags: nginx, timeout, valet

I found these for linux OS-

`proxy_connect_timeout 600; proxy_send_timeout 600; proxy_read_timeout 600; send_timeout 600;`

But I have install valet Nginx in windows and it is giving time out after 60secs.
Please help....

[I have found these files in Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jkr07.png)

Tried adding timeout code here but didn't work.